# PBS (torque) scheduler doesn't load my aliases from .bash_profile when a job runs?

Tags: bash, alias, pbs, torque

I have a bunch of alias declarations, functions, PATH additions, etc., in my .bash_profile file in my home directory. I also use PBS (torque) scheduling system. Normally, everything works fine and I can access my aliases from bash. However, when I submit a job, my aliases aren't getting loaded.

I thought maybe the .bash_profile file wasn't getting loaded when the job begins running, so in my job script I included a `~/.bash_profile` statement, and I can confirm that the file is being accessed by including a little `echo Testing!` statement, but still my aliases aren't working.

Here is an example of my .bash_profile:

```
alias tester='echo this is a test'
echo File was accessed!
```

Here is an example of my job script commands.sub:

```
tester
```

However, I invariably get this output:

```
tester: command not found
File was accessed!
```

Can anyone please provide me some advice for getting this working?! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases are intended for interactive use, and by default alias expansion does not occur in non-interactive shells. You could add

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

to the beginning of any script where you want to use any defined aliases.

However, I wouldn't recommend this. Since an alias could expand to *anything*, it's safer to limit command definitions to in-script definitions or explicitly sourced files.